# Shell Script: Passing Wrapper Parameters to Underlying Script

Tags: shell, parameters

I have created a wrapper which can execute a given script over SSH with following parameters

```
sshwrapper.sh <server> <script with path> <username> <password>
```

Now i want to invoke the following scripts:

```
start.sh param1 param2 param3 param4

stop.sh param1 param2 param3
```

using the same wrapper.

**Is it possible to have a mechanism where after passing the essential parameters to wrapper script I can post remaining parameters to underlying script?**

i.e. I would like to achieve following notation:

Examples:

```
sshwrapper.sh server start.sh username password param1 param2 param3 param4
```

should invoke

```
start.sh param1 param2 param3 param4
```

and

```
sshwrapper.sh server stop.sh username password param1 param2 param3
```

should invoke

```
stop.sh param1 param2 param3
```

in a generic manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `shift` and `"$@"`:

```
SERVER="$1"
SCRIPT="$2"
USERNAME="$3"
PASSWORD="$4"
shift 4

"$SCRIPT" "$@"
```

Example:

```
$ cat sshwrapper.sh 
#!/bin/sh

SERVER="$1"
SCRIPT="$2"
USERNAME="$3"
PASSWORD="$4"
shift 4

echo "$SCRIPT" "$@"

$ ./sshwrapper.sh server stop.sh username password param1 param2 param3 
stop.sh param1 param2 param3
```

Using `shift` you can remove first arguments from command line and shift the rest:

```
$ set 1 2 3 4 5
$ echo "$@"
1 2 3 4 5
$ shift 3
$ echo "$@"
4 5
```

You see here that `shift 3` removed first three arguments.

Comment: Excellent... I thought my question description was not clear enough but you exactly gave me something which i wanted. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

I have used ssh to execute scripts on remote servers previously, but to make my life easy I set up public-key authentication to allow *password-less* access.

See this article for reference

http://macnugget.org/projects/publickeys/

You can execute remote scripts with parameters using the default ssh tool from the command line as follows

```
$ ssh user@server "script.sh param1 param2 param3"
```

Multiple commands can be executed as follows

```
$ ssh user@server "script1.sh param1 param2 param3; script2.sh param1 param2 param3"
```

E.g - Loginto a remote server and print date and get a list of running processes

```
$ ssh user@server "echo date; ps -ef | grep hello"
```

You can add the above logic to your script, assuming you want to call this as part your ***ssh-wrapper***, or execute directly from the command line.

Just ensure you use **"double quotes"** instead of **'single'** in the ssh section.

Comment: +1. username, password was mentioned just to show that some parameters to be used by the wrapper. Anyways thanks for your response.